# Comparing nullable fields in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm having a problem with a stored procedure. It's comparing a new record with an existing one to check for changes. This is done like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM Table
WHERE Id= @Id
AND Field1 = @Field1
AND Field2 = @Field2
AND Field3 = @Field3
AND Field4 = @Field4
AND Field5 = @Field5
AND LEDTS IS NULL
```

This seems to fail when fields are NULL. I know = NULL doesn't work the way you might expect it to, but I didn't know it also fails in things like this. When I change the field comparison to things like

```
(Field1 IS NULL AND Field2 IS NULL) OR Field1 = @Field2
```

it does work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I am interested in this annoyance too.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SET ANSI_NULLS` can control this behavior...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) Setting `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` will make `NULL = NULL` evaluate to true.

But I would recommend against actually setting `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, and instead try to limit the fields in the database that are "nullable".

Comment: I'd recommend against it as well, especially since `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is a [deprecated feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I can't limit the number of nullable fields unfortunately, so I'll go with the ANSI_NULLS option. But i'll make sure to use it wisely ;)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli ok, but what would you recommend instead to do proper checks?

Comment: While it is cumbersome, the comparison that you posted is a good way to check for NULL values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use checks like this:

```
ISNULL(Field1, '') = ISNULL(@Field1, '')
```

There is a drowback doing this: you can have equalities like

```
NULL='' or ''=NULL
```

I dont't know if it could be acceptable in your scenario.

Comment: This is fine if performance is not an issue, but it is not sargable.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is governed by the `ANSI_NULLS` setting. This defaults to `ON`, and needs to be set this way for various things to work correctly (such as indexed views and distributed queries), but if you don't require those, you could switch it off.

Read more about it at [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

Comment: As I commented on another answer, note that `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is a [deprecated feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) that will be taken away at some point in the future.